# How to transfer /wordpress folder from one Mac to another

Tags: migration, localhost

I'm currently using Bitnami WordPress on Mac OS, to develop locally my new website, before uploading to the live server.

I'd like to copy the work-in-progress WP website from one Mac to another. I thought that it was simple as copying the WordPress folder found in Applications, but it doesn't work.

How should I proceed to copy the entire WP website from one Mac to the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the theme by going in the main WordPress folder `/wp-content/themes/your theme`. Copy that to the same location on the other Mac.

Now you'd have to export the database​or create another one on the other Mac and export all the files using the WordPress Backend. Go to Tools - Export and import the given file on the other Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The [Duplicator](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin is great for creating backups.

I use it for moving from local, to beta, to staging and finally production. It uses a simple wizard to set up a backup of your file system and database, then creates a deployment wizard to.

It's super easy, and free.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this, I was using MAMP. I had to create a MAMP install on the other machine, and then install Wordpress. Then, I imported the data (except for the table wp_options) and copied the /wp_content folder to the new machine.

Same with uploading to the live server. You have to leave the wp_options table because that's the table where WP stores site information.